# Displaying an entity pager in an article if that article is included in an entityqueue

Tags: views

I want to have a pager at the bottom of articles that a user can cycle through, that consists of other articles that are in the same entity queue list that the current article is also inside of.

I'm using Entityqueues to create arbitrary lists of articles and I'm using Entity Pager in a view to display that list of entity queue items a set of previous/next navigation links.

Within the entity pager view I have a Content queue relationship that limits to the specific entity queue list.

**ISSUE**: How can I make the entity pager know what entity queue list the current article is in, and then display its entity queue items at the bottom? And if the article isn't in any entity queue, the entity pager just won't show.